# Where to store cookies when running curl through cronjob?

Tags: php, cookies, cron

I have a PHP script that logs into a website with curl. When I run the script in a browser, the script logs in fine. When I run it through a cronjob, it does not log in, because the cookies are not stored where I expected.

How can I store the cookies?

---

This is the relevant part of the script. Before that the URL is defined ($url) and the login data ($post_string).

```
class curl {
    function __construct($use = 1) {
        $this->ch = curl_init();
        if($use = 1) {
            curl_setopt ($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt ($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/verwaltung/cookie.txt');
            curl_setopt ($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/verwaltung/cookie.txt');
            curl_setopt ($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt ($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        } else {
            return 'There is the possibility, that this script wont work';
        }
    }
    function first_connect($loginform,$logindata) {
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginform);
        curl_setopt ($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $logindata);
    }
    function store() {
        $store = curl_exec ($this->ch);
    }
    function execute($page) {
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $page);
        $this->content = curl_exec ($this->ch);
    }
    function close() {
        curl_close ($this->ch);
    }
    function __toString() {
        return $this->content;
    }
}

$getit = new curl();
$getit->first_connect($url, $post_string);
$getit->store();
$getit->execute($url);
$getit->close();
```

---

Question edited to reflect Wrikken's and Colin Morelli's comments below. Thank you both!

Comment: What is the class that `$getit` is an instance of? Does it have a `__toString()` method. If so, what does `__toString()` return? Etc, etc. We're missing some key components here.

Comment: With limited information available: you probably get another page (inspect `$getit`). The question is why...

Comment: @ColinMorelli I added more code. Does help?

Comment: @Wrikken I checked $getit (by mailing the output to myself), it contains the page I need to parse, no problem there. The script is all fine up until preg_match_all.

Comment: @what Are you sure you're getting the page you want? Because I can guarantee `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` isn't what you expect it to be in your curl class when you're running in the command line ;)

Comment: Ha ha, indeed, @ColinMorelli, you are right. I just checked the top of the page and did not look in the body. The problem must be the cookie, because my cronjob doesn't log me in. So where should I store the cookie? It needs to be a place where I can actually create the text file (which I don't know how to do through the shell, either). Do you know where and how? Oh, and please post an answer so I can choose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running your script from command line, the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable will be  empty (after all, there is no server and also no document root).

This means that `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/verwaltung/cookie.txt'` will eventually resolve to `'/verwaltung/cookie.txt'` (and a PHP notice). This directory will probably not exist (it's directly in the root filesystem; there shouldn't be anything besides the default Unix system directories) and your script will not be able to create the cookie file (and subsequently, not save any cookies set by cURL).

Instead of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, you could for example use `.` (the current directory), `/tmp` (should be writable by all users -- and also readable, be careful!), `__DIR__` (the directory the PHP script resides in) or any other directory at your discretion that does not depend on server variables.

Comment: Thank you, @helmbert. I spelled out the absolute path to the existing file, and now it works.